# Can not full width navbar bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to make full width navbar like [this](http://www.cssnewbie.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/centered-navbar-sketch.png). This my code:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <!--brand and menu-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar .container {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Why it keep body width (940px) ?

Comment: Is it inside the ``<div class="container">`` itself? You should probably post the full example containing the whole HTML code you have.

Comment: Setting the width of a child element to 100% will only make it span 100% of its parent. Therefore, unless `navbar-inner`, `navbar`, and any other parent elements are set to 100%, it will not work.

You could try setting its `position` to `absolute` and its `left` and `right` set to `0`.

Answer (score 9):

Use `container-fluid` instead of `container` class.

container class provides a fixed width layout. [Link](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts)

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!--brand and menu-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm so sorry everybody, I write max-width="1000px" on my css code so my header can't full width.
Thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I have no way of testing this, but this is how I would do this. You would first need to alter the width of the parent element, body:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Then from here, put the rest of the content in a div with class container:

```
<div class="container">
     Content Here
</div>
```

While changing the CSS for this container to something like:

```
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

I think this would make the width of the navbar full page and you can alter the middle content width based on the .container width percentage. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm so sorry everybody, I write max-width="1000px" on my css code so my header can't full width.
Thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry everybody, I write `max-width="1000px"` on my css code so my header can't full width.

Thanks for your kindly help.